# R Shiny app - big mysql query results in page not loading

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app which uses two mysql queries to retrieve data and the app works well when run from RStudio. (one of the queries is taking around 8 minutes)

But when I move it on a Shiny Server and access http://ip/myapp/, the page it's loading for a while and the I get `"Problem loading page"` .

I assume it's because the long query. Is there some good way to deal with this situation, when long queries have to be made from Shiny app?

-- (running locally `app.R` from RStudio, works fine)

Info about the app:

- Location: /srv/shiny-server/myapp
- Filename: app.r
- File structure:

  **-- load libraries**

  library(shiny)

  ...

  **-- Connection and queries**

  ```
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                   user = '#',
                   password = '#',
                   host = '#',
                   dbname='#')

  tickets<-dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from table")
  dbDisconnect (con)
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                   user = '#',
                   password = '#',
                   host = '#',
                   dbname='#')
  -- long query
  issues_speed_unique<-unique(na.omit(dbGetQuery(con,"Select * from table2")))
  dbDisconnect (con) 

  some aggregations....
  ```

  **-- Server code**

  ```
  shinyServer(
    function(input,output){
       ...
  ```

  **-- ui code**

  ```
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
       ...

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts) page out on shiny server administration. My guess is it's timing out due to taking more time than the server allows so it's timing out.

Comment: if the problem will persist, I would suggest to change the app architecture. You  can either: a) use faster DBs (monetdb comes to mind, or any in-memory db); b) try to load everything in memory at startup (e.g. using data.table library); c) or chunk your queries somehow (ultimately fetching less data). As a variant of a. you can experiment with out-of-core techniques like using ff library or similar tools (definitely no-sql though!). My favourite would be either a. or b. depending on use case.